# Batch script to upload file using FTP to a particular folder in remote server

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I am using [this script](http://www.howtogeek.com/50359/upload-files-to-an-ftp-site-via-a-batch-script/) to upload files using FTP. However, it is uploading to the root folder in the server.
Can any one tell me to upload the file to a particular path on remote server, say '/CurrentQA'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before this line:

```
ECHO binary >> %Commands%
```

Try adding this line:

```
ECHO cd /some/directory >> %Commands%
```

This should enter the desired directory in the remote server (I haven't tested it though).